# Best way to familiarize with Phonegap and Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova

I have been using angular for developing web applications.  Now I am starting a new project with phonegap and angularjs. Unfortunately I have no experience with mobile and phonegap in particular. I have googled for some tutorials but I was wondering if You can point to any articles, tutorials or book that You find useful?

I know that this question may be closed but I believe that the answers it receives will be useful for many people.

Comment: If you know it may be closed, why ask? All you are going to get in response are opinions reflecting the answerer's bias, which isn't really what SO is for.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some good advice, taken from [here](http://tricedesigns.com/presentations/dreamforce/native-like%20phonegap%20apps); and remember - don't use long lists - make pagination.

Here are the main points from the link:

- MOUSE EVENTS ARE SLOW - TOUCH EVENTS ARE FAST
- PRELOAD IMAGES
- USE HARDWARE ACCELERATION `transform: translate3d(0,0,0);` is your friend
- THROTTLE EVENT HANDLING `requestAnimationFrame();` or render loops mitigate CPU load
- AVOID GRATUITOUS ANIMATION/UI WHEN NOT CRITICAL